# Tkinter Entry justify text right when text is larger than the box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have some tk.Entry()s in my gui. The text inside the entries is always right-aligned. But once the text is larger than the box, the text is left-aligned.

Sample-Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

small_text = "abc"
big_text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
small_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, justify="right")
big_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, justify="right")
small_entry.insert(0, small_text)
big_entry.insert(0, big_text)
small_entry.pack()
big_entry.pack()

# what i want to see for big_entry:
wanna_see_text = "qrstuvwxyz"
wanna_see_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, justify="right")
wanna_see_entry.insert(0, wanna_see_text)
wanna_see_entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The result:

[image]

The first box is perfect.
Second box contains whole alphabet but it's left-aligned.
I want that the second box looks like the third box even if it contains the **entire** alphabet,

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `big_entry.xview_moveto(1)`

`xview_moveto()` requires a fraction between 0 and 1 (documentation [here](http://tkinter.fdex.eu/doc/caw.html))

Result :

[image: result]

Comment: The provided link is broken

Comment: Thx, link updated !